# Is it possible to run SSL and non-SSL web applications on same standalone Wildfly?

Tags: ssl, jboss, war, wildfly

Is it possible to run SSL and non-SSL web applications on same standalone Wildfly?

I am using Wildfly 8.1.0 (Undertow) and I am having troubles at configuring this scenario...
For example, I know how to configure either HTTP or HTTPS themselves, but whenever I try to run a configuration for both, the HTTP response is redirected to the SSL one... :(

Could somebody please point out what to change for example in the default standalone.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

first you need to add bellow code in ApplicationRealm

```
<server-identities>
    <ssl>
        <keystore path="server.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="abcd1234" alias="server" key-password="abcd1234"/>
    </ssl>
</server-identities>
```

Then you required to add lisner for both http and https

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default-http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <https-listener name="default-https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
        <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
        <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
    </host>
</server>
```

Now configure the connector for both http and https

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0">
    <endpoint worker="default"/>
    <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default-http" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    <http-connector name="https-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default-https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
</subsystem>
```

But generally people won't keep enable both http and https. They redirect the request from http to https.

Comment: thanks @Moes for your example, I am right now trying to use it. however why would you add SSL configuration for the HTTP ApplicationRealm? edit: I see there is only 1 applicationrealm, I was confused by your "both"

Comment: that is typo mistake. Correct sentence is "first you need to add bellow code in ApplicationRealm". Mark it as answer if it works.

Comment: yes I confirm it works, thanks! on another configuration file I have that automatic redirect you mentioned, that is undesired. P.S. please fix the answer typo